# Adding a Button in UITABLEVIEW's each cell at runtime based on condition

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

How to add a button in each table view cell at runtime i.e,(for ex) if the given condition is true red color button should be displayed , green color button should be displayed if it is false? how to implement that?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: I am just a beginner in objective-c...

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all cells of the table view by doing the following:

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [yourTableView numberOfSections]; ++i)
{
    for (NSInteger j = 0; j < [yourTableView numberOfRowsInSection:i]; ++j)
    {
        //Put your code here to check whatever, and add a UIButton to each cell.

        //The object below represents each cell of your tableView.
        //[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:i]];
    }
}
```

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: thanks for the idea and immediate reply....But I am a newbie in objective-c/ios... code snippet would be better to understand and learn.....

Comment: The code I've posted should be enough to get you started.  What have you tried so far?  I understand your question, however it seems as though all you need to do is all a UIButton into each of those cells and make it red or green depending on a certain criteria.

Comment: I am completely new to objective-c/ios development. Where should I use the above snippet? tableView willDisplayCell or in some other methods